# Having several meshes with the same material

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tiles, tile

I'm currently trying to find an efficient way to draw tile maps in Unity. The way my system works is that I build a level by sticking together a bunch of rooms which consist of tiles. I followed this tutorial for [my solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owBt9SNKXCI).

Right now, I'm generating a new mesh for every room I have and then placing the textures I want on the right positions on a material. However, I currently use one material prefab which all the rooms use. This means that because all the rooms overwrite the same material, the tiles don't fit anymore for the other rooms.

Here's what I mean. This is when I only have one room, as you can see since this is the only room modifying the material the tiles are all correct:[image: correct tiles]

But when I make several rooms, they all modify the same texture. This means that the last room to modify the texture has its tiles correctly placed while the rest of the rooms are incorrect:
[image]

This is the actual room the material works for:
[image]

My question is, is there a way to save the meshes I build for the rooms without them depending on the same material? Of course, just making 100 materials separately for every room would work but that is just nonsense. I want to save the mesh I build for a room "as is" or make all the different meshes I create not depend on a single material.

(roughly)The code I use right now for making the correct material for a room:

```
public void BuildTextures(Room room)
{
    Sprite ground = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Background Sprites/Tile 2");

    int texWidth = (room.Width + 1) * (int)ground.textureRect.width;
    int texHeight = (room.Height + 1) * (int)ground.textureRect.height;
    int tileWidth = (int)ground.textureRect.width;
    int tileHeight = (int)ground.textureRect.height;

    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(texWidth, texHeight);

    texture.SetPixels(x * (int)ground.textureRect.width, y * (int)ground.textureRect.height, (int)ground .textureRect.width, (int)ground .textureRect.height, ground.GetPixels()); //ground.GetPixels technically doesn't exist for a sprite, but I created a function which yields the same result. This is not important

    texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
    texture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
    texture.Apply();

    MeshRenderer meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    meshRenderer.sharedMaterials[0].mainTexture = texture;
}
```

Comment: The very first sentence of the tag [tag:Unity] is "DO NOT USE ON QUESTIONS ABOUT THE UNITY GAME ENGINE (use: [tag:unity3d] instead)"

Comment: Oops, wasn't really paying attention there. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: You're accessing `sharedMaterials`, which shares a material instance between all meshes with that material. If you instead access `materials`, Unity will internally copy a new material instance for each mesh.

Comment: Wow! Thanks rutter, that was exactly what I needed! I'm glad it was quite a simple solution in the end :D